# on default load , highlight the particular Column according to the current month with color in the HTML table using Angular js or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 10 products with sales data for every month. I need to highlight the entire column according to the current month and year in the table using Angular JS. We will have data future expected sales as well. Please find attached image in detail.

[image]

Comment: please share the sample data

Comment: What have you tried? Please share the code you've used to try to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using moment and compare today's Month, Year with header.

Below is the working example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.21.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.6" data-semver="1.6.6" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
      app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = [{"Product":"Body Spray","Location":"USA","Dec-2017":"234","Jan-18":"789","Feb-18":"234","Mar-18":"789","Apr-18":"234"},{"Product":"Groceries","Location":"USA","Dec-2017":"234","Jan-18":"789","Feb-18":"234","Mar-18":"789","Apr-18":"234"},{"Product":"Ready Cook","Location":"USA","Dec-2017":"234","Jan-18":"789","Feb-18":"234","Mar-18":"789","Apr-18":"234"},{"Product":"Vegetables","Location":"USA","Dec-2017":"234","Jan-18":"789","Feb-18":"234","Mar-18":"789","Apr-18":"234"}];
        $scope.checkIfCurrentMonth = function(shortData){
          return moment().format('MMM-YY') === shortData;
        };
      });
    }());
  </script>
  <style>
    .highlightBorder{
      border: solid 5px #979797 !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in data[0] as header"  ng-class="{'highlightBorder':checkIfCurrentMonth(key)}">
          {{ key }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td data-ng-repeat="(key, val) in data[0]" ng-class="{'highlightBorder':checkIfCurrentMonth(key)}">
          {{ row[key] }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```